# What is the workaround code to detect network changes from Nougat and further android versions >

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am using below code to detect network changes

```
public class NetworkStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static int NETWORK_CONNECTED_TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int NETWORK_CONNECTED_TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int NO_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY = 0;
public static int TYPE_NOT_KNOWN = -1;

private static final List<NetworkStateChangeListener> LISTENERS = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int status = getConnectivityStatus(context, intent);
    networkChecking(status);

}

private void networkChecking(int noNetworkConnectivity) {
    for (NetworkStateChangeListener mlistener : LISTENERS) {
        if (mlistener != null) {
            mlistener.onNetworkStateChanged(noNetworkConnectivity);
        }
    }
}


public static void registerNetworkState(NetworkStateChangeListener listener) {
    synchronized (LISTENERS) {
        if (!LISTENERS.contains(listener)) {
            LISTENERS.add(listener);
        }
    }
}

public static void unregisterNetworkState(NetworkStateChangeListener listener) {
    LISTENERS.remove(listener);
}


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetwork!=null) {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                return NETWORK_CONNECTED_TYPE_WIFI;
            }

            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                return NETWORK_CONNECTED_TYPE_MOBILE;
            }

        }
        return NO_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY;
    }

    return TYPE_NOT_KNOWN;
}
```

}

and initialising below intent filters in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".utils.network.NetworkStateListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This code is working fine for below Marshmallow devices 6.0.1. But from 7 Nougat onwards, its not working.

What is the code change in Nougat?

Any code or gist will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution:

Register programmatically like this

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(); 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { // **For Nougat**
    intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTI‌​ON); 
} else {
    intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE));   
}

registerReceiver(new NetworkConnectionReceiver(), intentFilter);
```

Comment: But this works only if the app is running, right? It does not behave like an implicit Receiver anymore since it does not listen in the background even when the app is not running.